# How to find if a values exists in all rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of unique elements and a dataframe.
I want to find out if the elements in the array exist in all the row of the dataframe.
p.s- I am new to python.

This is the piece of code I've written.

```
for i in uniqueArray:
    for index,row in newDF.iterrows():
        if i in row['MKT']:
            #do something to find out if the element i exists in all rows
```

Also, this way of iterating is quite expensive, is there any better way to do the same?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: You could use `np.isin(uniqueArray, newDF.MKT).all(0)` to determine which elements of `uniqueArray` are contained in all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allow you to filter a whole column like if it was Excel:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.Dataframe(tableData)
```

Imagine your columns names are "Column1", "Column2"... etc

```
df2 = df[ df["Column1"] == "ValueToFind"]
```

df2 now has only the rows that has "ValueToFind" in df["Column1"]. You can concatenate several filters and use AND OR logical doors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for i in uniqueArray:
    if newDF['MKT'].contains(i).any():
        # do your task
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin()` method of pd.Series object.

Assuming you have a data frame named `df` and you check if your column `'MKT'` includes any items of your `uniqueArray`.

```
new_df = df[df.MKT.isin(uniqueArray)].copy()
```

new_df will only contain the rows where values of MKT is contained in unique Array.

Now do your things on new_df, and join/merge/concat to the former df as you wish.